# snprintf not working as expected with avr-gcc

Tags: c, avr, avr-gcc, atmel, atmelstudio

During a debugging session, I found out that [`snprintf`](http://www.microchip.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/group__avr__stdio_1ga77070c245d4ca4f7ec7d7144260fb875.html) is not working as expected when compiling the code with avr-gcc. The example code should simply convert the floating point value `3999.9f` into its character representation.

Here is a minimal test case:

```
    int TestSnprintf(void)
    {
       const float inputValue = 3999.9f;
       /* Print with a fixed width of 6 characters (5 numbers and 1 dot).
       The buffer must have a length of 7, because snprintf appends a '\0' at the end. */
       char buf[7U] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
       const uint8_t bufferSize = 7U;
       if(6 != snprintf(buf, bufferSize, "%06.1f", inputValue))
       {
          return -1;
       }
       if( buf[0] != '3'
            || buf[1] != '9'
            || buf[2] != '9'
            || buf[3] != '9'
            || buf[4] != '.'
            || buf[5] != '9'
            || buf[6] != '\0')
      {
          return -2;
      }

      return 0;
   }

   int main(void)
   {
     int retVal = TestSnprintf();
     return 0;
   }
```

Compiling this example code with avr-gcc and running it with Atmel Studio 7 gives a return value of **-2**. This means `snprintf` is not working.

**What I have tried so far:**

- I tested the code on 32 and 64 bit Linux and it works as expected (`TestSnprintf` return the value 0).
- I tested the code with Visual Studio 2015 and it worked as expected (`TestSnprintf` return the value 0).
- The content of `buf` is

  ```
  buf[0] = 32;    
  buf[1] = 32;    
  buf[2] = 32;    
  buf[3] = 32;    
  buf[4] = 32;    
  buf[5] = 63;    
  buf[6] = 0;
  ```
- The testing is performed on the device using the JTAG interface. I tried the simulator as well, with the same result.
- No compiler optimization is activated. The code is compiled and debugged with `-O0`.

Here is a screenshot from the debugging session, that demonstrates that the return value is **-2**.

[image]

This demonstrates that `buf` is in scope during debugging:
[image]

**Question**

What am I doing wrong?

**SOLUTION**

First of all thank you all very much for your help! 
As pointed out by @manilo the following linker options were missing:

```
-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt -lm
```

Comment: And the C standard library is not part of gcc! Which library do you use?

Comment: You should find out what  `buf` actually contains.

Comment: Did you link with `libm` ? (`-lm`)

Comment: Why the downvote ? The question is well formatted, easy to understand, offending code is included, OP stated what he has tried..

Comment: Is `<stdio.h>` included beforehand?

Comment: @chux yes it's included

Comment: How do you check the content of `buf`?

Comment: According to this: http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html#gaa3b98c0d17b35642c0f3e4649092b9f1 you need `-lm` did you link it in?

Comment: @fukanchik Wouldn't it just fail to link id he didn't?

Comment: @EugeneSh. By running the debugging the code via JTAG directly on the device. I also tried running in the simulator, same result. I tried changing the device, with the same result.

Comment: @fukanchik Yes i link with libm

Comment: @orbitcowboy Are you sure you are breaking in the right place? Do you have any other variable named `buf` around? Can you show the *full* code?

Comment: BTW, it can be very well optimized away, as your test code is doing nothing...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Good point, i added a screenshot that demonstrated that the break point is placed correctly. But Olaf told me is should'nt add them. I'll re-add it.

Comment: Are you sure the `printf` family is implemented? In general on such small targets like AVR, using these heavyweights is not a good idea. Better write custom functions for simple conversions and use them.

Comment: @orbitcowboy Well, Olaf meant that the code should not come in pictures. But if there is some extra info that can be shown by picture only - it should be OK..

Comment: @orbitcowboy: I did not tell to remove information. Just there is no need to haver the screenshot! Use **text**!

Comment: @orbitcowboy In the place you are showing `buf` is out of scope.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: There should be no problem showing the breakpoint in a comment.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I will add another screenshot with the break point at return -2, that demonstrates buf is not out of scope.

Comment: I think the answers below are making sense..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are three different implementations of `printf()` (and friends). The default doesn't implement float output.

`snprintf` won't work without linking `libprintf_flt.a` (`-lprintf_flt`) and `libm.a` (`-lm`).

Also, according to the documentation, you have to add the linker options `-Wl,-u,vfprintf` (e.g. [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180411145531/http://winavr.scienceprog.com/avr-gcc-tutorial/using-sprintf-function-for-float-numbers-in-avr-gcc.html)).

The sequence of the linker flags is important: `-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt -lm`

Answer (score 0):

"Also note that by default the Arduino IDE does not set the AVR linker options to support floating point in the xxprintf() routines. So while that saves quite a bit of code space on the AVR builds, it means that printf() functions cannot be used for floating point output on the AVR. Floating support is included by default for the other processors." http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/Printf

Comment: I am using Atmel Studio not  an Arduino IDE.